# Handling `CRLF` line endings in substitution and `split` in Perl

Tags: csv, perl, text, newline

I need to process many files (with `CRLF` line endings) that look like that:

```sh
$ cat -v file1.txt
1$XXX$ZZZ$$$$$$$$^M
2$AAA$BBB$$$$$$$$^M

$ cat -v file2.txt
1$4668$$$^M
2$46$$$^M
```

I need to:

- remove the last `$` sign,
- change all `$` to `,`,
- enclose each field in double quotes,
- rename the files.

Desired output (no matter if line endings are `CRLF` or `LF`):

```sh
$ cat newname1.csv
"1","XXX","ZZZ","","","","","","",""
"2","AAA","BBB","","","","","","",""

$ cat newname2.csv
"1","4668","",""
"2","46","",""
```

Here is my attempt:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %inputs = qw(
  file1 file1.txt
  file2 file2.txt
);

my %outputs = qw(
  file1 newname1.csv
  file2 newname2.csv
);

for my $key (keys %inputs) {
  
  open my $in, '<', $inputs{$key} or die $!;
  open my $out, '>', $outputs{$key} or die $!;
  
  while(<$in>) {
    local $, = ',';
    local $\ = "\n";
    s/\$$//;
    my @row = split /\$/;
    print $out map qq("$_"), @row;
  }
  
  close $in or die $!;
  close $out or die $!;
  
}
```

On Linux, it gives files with a `CRLF` enclosed in the last column and `LF` line endings:

```sh
$ cat -v newname1.csv
"1","XXX","ZZZ","","","","","","","","^M
"
"2","AAA","BBB","","","","","","","","^M
"

$ cat -v newname2.csv
"1","4668","","","^M
"
"2","46","","","^M
"
```

I guess the issue is due to `CRLF` line endings. Therefore, I tried:

- to change `'<'` to `'<:crlf'` to open my files, which gives the same result;
- to use other regex to match the last `$` sign (e.g. `\$\r\n` and `\$\R`, which both result in files without the empty trailing columns).

How can I fix my code to get my desired output?

Comment: To see which line endings you have, use a module such as `Data::Dumper`. E.g. `perl -MData::Dumper -ne'$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $_;'`

Comment: Wow, did you just change your question again, making my answer completely wrong? Ugh. That's not nice, you know.

Comment: My Text::CSV solution should at least fix your problem, if you can adjust for the CRLF. You can probably use that. I'm not going to attempt it, because you've already changed the question twice and made me redo my work from scratch each time.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question several times. As you pointed out, the 2 previous versions had issues (missing line in the script in V1 or output not matching the script in V2). However, your answer about `split`'s third argument fixed my issue. You can undelete your answer, and I will accept it. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: @Thomas I'm not so sure it did fix your issue, or it is just a coincidence, but if you are ok with it, I guess its ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: This answer was written for the first two versions of the question. I only undeleted it because the OP asked me to. It may not fit the current version of the question. Some things might be outright wrong.

---

This has nothing to do with line endings being CRLF. It is just a [`split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) issue.

If I add a Dumper print to your code, where you have split into the variable `@row`

```
my @row = split /\$/;
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@row;
```

I get (for the first field):

```
$VAR1 = [
          '1',
          '4668',
          '',
          '',
          '
'
        ];
```

Where you can see the trailing newline is the last field in your split.

When you then treat these split results as genuine column values in your data, you get 1 field added for the newline.

I do not see where you are removing the last `$`. Maybe that is something you misunderstood?

**Suggested solution:**

If this is csv data, you should use a csv module to handle it. The [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module does this well. Here's a sample code that will handle your inputs:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV qw(csv);

my %inputs = qw(
  file1 file1.txt
  file2 file2.txt
);

my %outputs = qw(
  file1 newname1.csv
  file2 newname2.csv
);

for my $key (keys %inputs) {
    my $aoa = csv (in => $inputs{$key}, sep_char => '$');
    csv (in => $aoa, out => $outputs{$key}, sep_char => ',', always_quote => 1);
}
```

Update:

Since you edited your question and added a line of code that changes *everything* and makes your own claimed output "wrong", I've found the following:

If you have only trailing empty fields, [`split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) will delete those empty fields by default. This can be fixed, as specified in the [documentation for split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split):

> If LIMIT is negative, it is treated as if it were instead arbitrarily
> large; as many fields as possible are produced.
>
> If LIMIT is omitted (or, equivalently, zero), then it is usually
> treated as if it were instead negative but with the exception that
> trailing empty fields are stripped (empty leading fields are always
> preserved); if all fields are empty, then all fields are considered to
> be trailing (and are thus stripped in this case).

In other words, you can change

```
split /\$/;
```

to

```
split /\$/, $_, -1;
```

to fix your missing trailing empty fields.

The only problem is that you have not reported having this problem (yet). So, I guess we need to wait for you to update your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I updated my question to add how I am removing the last `$` (I had deleted the line by mistake before posting).

Comment: You should never, ever post code that is not exactly what you ran when you got the result you say you did. You just wasted my time, and now I have to start from the beginning to test and see if my answer is even relevant anymore.

Comment: When I run your *new* code, I get "1","XXX","ZZZ" instead for first row. So maybe you should check what *you* get on your system and update your question.

Comment: @Thomas Actually, the correct solution is probably to use the `Text::CSV` module like I showed. If this is indeed csv data, the safest way to handle it is with a csv module. Otherwise, you risk breaking your data. As you can see, it is also somewhat easier.

Comment: FYI, I have added an answer to clarify the issue and some solutions for future readers. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the credit. You should probably investigate the Text::CSV module and see if you can incorporate that into a viable answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: The purpose of this answer is to clarify the issue and some solutions for future readers (due to my ill-timed edits of my question). Credit should go to [@TLP answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76101263/11148823). Also, as he suggested, the correct solution is probably to use the `Text::CSV` module, but deciphering the issue was educational.*

---

There are two issues in the code:

1. when using `\$\r\n` or `\$\R` to match the last `$` sign, it works as expected. However, since the last columns are empty (i.e. no `CRLF` get enclosed in the last column), [`split` drop them by default](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split).
2. when using `\$$` to match the last `$` sign, a `CRLF` get enclosed in the last column (I don't understand why);

On Linux, a possible fix is to:

- specify `split`'s `LIMIT` argument by changing `split /\$/;` into `split /\$/, $_, -1;` (to fix issue 1);
- *and* (to fix issue 2) either:

  - change the regex to match the last `$` sign from `\$$` to `\$\r\n` (or `\$\R`); (referred to as `myscript_fix1.pl` below)
  - or add `local $/ = "\r\n"; chomp;` at the beginning of the `while` loop and keep the regex `\$$` to match the last `$`; (referred to as `myscript_fix2.pl` below)
  - or keep the last `$` sign (i.e. drop `s/\$$//;`) and add `pop @row;` after `split`. (referred to as `myscript_fix3.pl` below)

On Windows, some adjustments are needed.

Some timings on my machine using `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` duplicated 10000 times:

```bash
$ time myscript_fix1.pl
real    0m0,199s
user    0m0,179s
sys     0m0,018s

$ time myscript_fix2.pl
real    0m0,234s
user    0m0,215s
sys     0m0,017s

$ time myscript_fix3.pl
real    0m0,176s
user    0m0,159s
sys     0m0,016s
```